# Query comparing dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, compare

I have a table with  dates that all happened in the month November.
I wrote this query

```
select id,numbers_from,created_date,amount_numbers,SMS_text 
from Test_Table
where 
created_date <= '2013-04-12'
```

This query should return everything that happened in month 11 (November) because it happened **before** the date '2013-04-12' (in December)

But it's only returning available dates that happened in days lesser than 04 (2013-**04**-12)

Could it be that it's only comparing the day part? and not the whole date?

How to fix this?

Created_date is of type **date**

Date format is by default **yyyy-dd-MM**

Comment: You are comparing dates to strings, not dates to dates

Comment: Maybe it thinks `2013-04-12`? is April 12th? Or maybe `created_date`is a string and not a date?

Comment: Look at [Cast & Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) on T-SQL manual and use the appropriate conversion for your locale

Comment: No need to cast at all, just use the invariant format '20130412'

Comment: @Jpw no not April. Because it's returning all the dates in November that happened in days less than 4

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Still returning the same result: All the dates in November that happened in days less than 4.

Comment: @Steve I already did convert the date to its right format. The problem is that its returning all the dates in November that happened in days less than 4, so its working but its only comparing the day part

Comment: Oops, if you want December, you should try '20131204'. Who ever puts the month at the end?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos '20131204' is returning everything before April

Comment: @HelpASisterOut is your date actually a `DATE` or is it something it shouldn't be like `VARCHAR(n)`

Comment: @TI It's of type : date

Comment: @HelpASisterOut what are you using to query the database? SSMS or other?

Comment: @TI Sending the query from my VB code. So ADO.

Comment: Instead of sending a string with the date then, try creating a parameterized query and pass the date as a date-typed parameter. BTW what version of SQL Server are you using? DATE was added in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Also, are you SURE you aren't interpretting the result's MONTH as the DAY? What you describe until now is atypical - unless you have mixed months with dates. yyyy-dd-mm is not the default format for date, according [to the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352(v=sql.100).aspx) it is interpreted as yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: I parameterized the query and passed the date as a date and it worked. Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos for keeping up

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Instead of '2013-04-12' whose meaning depends on the local culture, use '20130412' which is recognized as the culture invariant format.

If you want to compare with December 4<sup>th</sup>, you should write '20131204'. If you want to compare with April 12<sup>th</sup>, you should write '20130412'.

The article [Write International Transact-SQL Statements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191307.aspx) from SQL Server's documentation explains how to write statements that are culture invariant:

> Applications that use other APIs, or Transact-SQL scripts, stored procedures, and triggers, should use the unseparated numeric strings. For example, yyyymmdd as 19980924.

**EDIT**

Since you are using ADO, the best option is to parameterize the query and pass the date value as a date parameter. This way you avoid the format issue entirely and gain the performance benefits of parameterized queries as well.

**UPDATE**

To use the the the ISO 8601 format in a literal, all elements must be specified. To quote [from the ISO 8601 section of datetime's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

> To use the ISO 8601 format, you must specify each element in the format. This also includes the T, the colons (:), and the period (.) that are shown in the format.
>
> ... the fraction of second component is optional. The time component is specified in the 24-hour format.

Comment: @andy not exactly, the ISO8601 format *includes* the time element. Or [as the docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), `To use the ISO 8601 format, you must specify each element in the format. This also includes the T`.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, my point was that ISO8601 defines the order just the way you described: YYYY-MM-DD or for short YYYYMMDD. However, as the docs also state: "datetime is not ANSI or ISO 8601 compliant.". The ISO itself would not require a time part.

Comment: What you refer to doesn't change the fact that `YYYY-MM-DD` is *not* recognized as ISO 8601. The time parts *are* required. Call it T-SQL's strangeness if you will, or incomplete implementation. It may even be that this was carried over from Sybase

Answer (score 37):

Try like this

```
select id,numbers_from,created_date,amount_numbers,SMS_text 
from Test_Table
where 
created_date <= '2013-12-04'
```

Comment: Culture specific format. Is that 12 April or 4 December? The dash-separated format is NOT the international format

Comment: It is 4 December, since the server is in that culture , i think we don't want to worry more about culture. Anyway we are not going to change the db server culture recently. Your point is correct but i don't think my answer is wrong.

Comment: So what happens when you need to store data from international clients? Or the date comes from a web browser which follows the *user's* culture? The guidelines exist for a reason, and by simply NOT using the wrong format, you avoid all errors

Comment: @Nithesh This is returning April 12th

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The dash-separated format **is** the international format ever since [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) was published in 1988. Other formats are discouraged and [ridiculed](http://xkcd.com/1179/). Even the article you posted, ["Write International Transact-SQL Statements"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191307.aspx) never once identifies 'yyyymmdd' as any kind of "international" standard.

Comment: @JesseWebb SQL Server server doesn't interpret dash-separated *dates* as *ISO 8601* unless you pass them as an ODBC timestamp (eg.  `{ d '1998-09-24' }`). The article I posted  *does* mention this, and *does* say you need to use the unseparated format as the only one that is guaranteed to work when using T-SQL. I quoted the relevant excerpt in my answer. There are multiple SO questions from people that *did* have problems when passing the *date* in a dash-separated format

Comment: Adding single quotes around the date resolved this for me. Was using format 2/19/2015. Changed to '2/19/2015' and it started working. Thanks for the simple idea.

Answer (score 17):

If You are comparing only with the date vale, then converting it to date (not **datetime**) will work

```
select id,numbers_from,created_date,amount_numbers,SMS_text 
 from Test_Table
 where 
 created_date <= convert(date,'2013-04-12',23)
```

This conversion is also applicable during using **GetDate()** function

-- Updating cast number as per the suggestion of @Thomas853

Comment: Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15, it should be style 23 and not 102. Style 23 is ISO8601 (yyyy-mm-dd) and style 102 is ANSI (yyyy.mm.dd).

Answer (score 5):

please try with below query

```
select id,numbers_from,created_date,amount_numbers,SMS_text 
from Test_Table
where 
convert(datetime, convert(varchar(10), created_date, 102))  <= convert(datetime,'2013-04-12')
```

Answer (score 5):

You put `<=` and it will catch the given date too. You can replace it with `<` only.

Answer (score 2):

**Convert them to dates in the same format** and then you can compare. Τry like this:

```
where convert(date, created_date,102) <= convert(date,                                  /*102 is ANSI format*/
                                                    substring('2013-04-12',1,4) + '.' + /*year*/
                                                    substring('2013-04-12',9,2) + '.' + /*month*/
                                                    substring('2013-04-12',6,2)         /*day*/
                                                ,102)
```

Answer (score 1):

Date format is yyyy-mm-dd.
So the above query is looking for records older than 12Apr2013

Suggest you do a quick check by setting the date string to '2013-04-30', if no sql error, date format is confirmed to yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 1):

Below query can be used to find the records of month November for the year 2013.

```
Select id,numbers_from,created_date,amount_numbers,SMS_text 
from Test_Table
where Month(created_date) = 11 and Year(created_date) = 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "#" before and after of the date and be sure of your system date format. maybe "YYYYMMDD O YYYY-MM-DD O MM-DD-YYYY O USING '/ O \' "

Ex:

```
 select id,numbers_from,created_date,amount_numbers,SMS_text 
 from Test_Table
 where 
 created_date <= #2013-04-12#
```

Answer (score 0):

For my queries on MS Access, I can compare dates with this syntax:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(orderNumber) AS Total
FROM Orders
WHERE orderDate >=#2003/04/01#
AND orderDate <=#2003/06/30#;
```

Where the output is the number of orders between 2003-04-01 and 2003-06-30.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use to_char(column_name, 'YYYY-MM-DD) to change format

Comment: There is no TO_CHAR in SQL Server. See [Using TO_CHAR function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58726796/11154841).