# Dapper Extensions for Date comparision using Predicate

Tags: dapper-extensions

How do you compare the date values using predicate group

this is what I have been trying to do

```
    var predicateGroup = new PredicateGroup { Operator = GroupOperator.And, Predicates = new List<IPredicate>() };
    predicateGroup.Predicates.Add(Predicates.Field<Contents>(f => f.Guid, Operator.Eq, staticContents.Guid));
    predicateGroup.Predicates.Add(Predicates.Field<Contents>(f => f.StartDate, Operator.Ge, DateTime.UtcNow));
    predicateGroup.Predicates.Add(Predicates.Field<Contents>(f => f.EndDate, Operator.Le, DateTime.Now));
```

I am trying to pick the value with a specific GUID and the want it to lie between the required startdate and enddate.

I tried the BetweenValue as well but it dosent seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing dates:

Instead of doing:

```
predicateGroup.Predicates.Add(Predicates.Field<Contents>(f => f.EndDate, Operator.Le, DateTime.Now));
```

You may also compare on the ISO8601 string representation of the date. "2015-12-31". Like this:

```
predicateGroup.Predicates.Add(Predicates.Field<Contents>(f => f.EndDate, Operator.Le, "2015-12-31"));
```

Read more about [Query comparing dates in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924236/query-comparing-dates-in-sql) in another Stack overflow post. This post also links to  [an MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) explaining how to format culture invariant string formats for dates and also date-times if that may be your issue.

Also remember that the argument **Operator.Ge** by default will render ">=",  while **Operator.Gt** by default renders ">" if that could be the case. The same goes for **Operator.Le**/**Operator.Lt**. (This is probably not the issue here since .Gt and .Lt will shrink your 'between' interval)