# How to get previous dates available from today's date, and check condition for every previous dates using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

Here, I like to explain my problem clearly,
I have table called `claims` in that there is field called `TRT`(turn around time).
In this field user set a date(example: 2015-07-09), 
Every time admin used to check a pendings availble or not, example: if today's date and TRT date is same then the Pending data automatically moves to another table.

so what i did is ,

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$dt1 = ArrayHelper::map(Importclaims::find()->all(),'id','turn_around_time_set');

foreach ($dt1 as $key => $value) 
        {
            $trt = print_r($value, true);

            if($today == $trt)
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO importpending (claimer_name, status, template, last_trt, email) 
                        SELECT employee_name, status_new, template, turn_around_time_set, tpa  
                        FROM importclaims WHERE id = $name1 ";

                $query = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();

                echo '<div class="alert alert-success"> Pendings Availble </div>';

            }
            else
            {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success"> No Pendings Availble </div>';
            }
            // return $this->redirect(['index']);


        }
```

but this executing only those TRT equal to today's date, but i need to check every TRT date which is lesser than equal todays date.

simply, Insert data those TRT date less and equal to today's date

Comment: can you give me a idea

Comment: I don't see table `claims` or column `TRT` used in your code ?

Comment: you can see turn_around_time and importclaims

Comment: i need **if** condition those TRT <= today, but i dont know how to check

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the answer,

```
$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$dt1 = ArrayHelper::map(Importclaims::find()->all(),'id','turn_around_time_set');
 foreach ($dt1 as $key => $value) 
        {
            $trt = print_r($value, true);
            $new = strtotime($trt);
if($new <= $today)
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO importpending (claimer_name, status, template, last_trt, email) 
                        SELECT employee_name, status_new, template, turn_around_time_set, tpa  
                        FROM importclaims WHERE id = $name1 ";

                $query = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();

                echo '<div class="alert alert-success"> Pendings Availble </div>';

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use where clauses in your insert queries - but 
if you have to, you would have to write your query like that:

```
"INSERT INTO importpending (claimer_name, status, template, last_trt, email)
                        (SELECT employee_name, status_new, template,  
                        turn_around_time_set, tpa  
                        FROM importclaims
                        WHERE id = $name1 AND TRT < '".$today."')";
```

Please note that you will have to change your date format to make this work. 
More information about date formats in mysql you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924236/query-comparing-dates-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in single SQL Query, see below example:

```
INSERT INTO importpending (`claimer_name`, `status`, `template`, `last_trt`, `email`) 
SELECT  
    `employee_name`, `status_new`, `template`, `turn_around_time_set`, `tpa`  
FROM importclaims 
WHERE turn_around_time <= NOW()
```