# Date Overlapping Result

Tags: mysql, database

In the `hire` table, there are date range between `start_date` and `end_date`

Client choose between two dates to hire, it need to make sure it does not overlap between `start_date` and `end_date` that already exist in the table

For example in the `hire` table

```
id,    start_date,           end_date
-------------------------------------------------
3   2015-10-23 00:00:00,     2015-10-30 23:59:59
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT *  FROM `hire` WHERE DATE(`start_date`) >= '2015-10-24' AND DATE(`end_date`) <= '2015-10-26'
```

For some reason, it is not showing any result?

I also need to show the result because end_date is over-lapped as well

```
DATE(`start_date`) >= '2015-10-27' AND DATE(`end_date`) <= '2015-10-31'
```

This should show no result:

```
DATE(`start_date`) >= '2015-10-31' AND DATE(`end_date`) <= '2015-11-02'
```

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924236/query-comparing-dates-in-sql

Comment: In your example start_date is 2015-10-23. The dates you are comparing with are always later. Therefore start_date is always less than and never greater or equal.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the logic you want is this:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM `hire` h
WHERE DATE(`start_date`) <= '2015-10-26' AND
      DATE(`end_date`) >= '2015-10-24';
```

This gets anyone who is active during that period of time.

Comment: That kinda work but if I choose later end date, it should still show result because it is overlapped: For example: `DATE(`start_date`) <= '2015-10-24' AND DATE(`end_date`) >= '2015-11-05'`