# Listing later dates in comparison to another entry in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I list the students who started later than start year of student with id = 8871?

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT sid s1
FROM Student
WHERE s1.started <= sid = '8871';
```

I went to this link for some reference but I'm still having issues:
[Query comparing dates in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924236/query-comparing-dates-in-sql)

Student Table has:
Student (Lastname, Firstname, SID, Started)

any help would be great

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a [self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it) where one side of the join contains the students you want and the the reference student 8871:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   student a
JOIN   student b ON b.sid = '8871' AND a.started  > b.started
```

Comment: Thanks for linking the self join, im still new to this!