# Using TO_CHAR function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to execute this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Production
WHERE TO_CHAR(Time_Stamp, "DD/MM/YYYY") = current_date
AND TO_CHAR(Time_STAMP, "HH:MM:SS") BETWEEN "00:00:00" AND "07:00:00"
```

My Time_Stamp field looks like : `"DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS"`

Unfortunately, function `TO_CHAR` doesn't exist in SQL Server.

How can I transform my query so it can work on SQL Server?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: Unrelated, but: using `TO_CHAR(Time_Stamp, "DD/MM/YYYY") = current_date` in Oracle (or Postgres) is a **really** bad idea to begin with. You are comparing a string to a DATE value

Comment: I want to sort all the data that had been add during the night.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `TO_CHAR` in SQL Server. If you need to pass a date use the ISO formats `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssssss` or for a time just `hh:mm:ss.sssssss`.

Seeing, however, that is seems you have values that are for today (I assume that is what `current_date` is), looks like you want this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Production
WHERE Time_Stamp >= DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0)
  AND Time_Stamp < DATEADD(HOUR,7,DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0));
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are using ```DATEADD()``` ?

Comment: As you want times between 7 and 8 @MissKnacki , so I'm added 7 hours to the current date.

Comment: I wanted to try this method but SQL server tell me that DATEDIFF function need 3 arguments...

Comment: Sorry, @MissKnacki, there was a typographical error. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Oh ok ! Thanks, now it's working but I have data just the data of one hour instead of datas between midnight and 7am.

Comment: Try now, @MissKnacki. Looks like I had misread your question. I probably hadn't started my coffee when i answered.

Comment: I have all the data I want now ! Thank you @Larnu ! Do you know how can I also have the datas of the day before current date, between 20pm et 12pm ? All in one query

Comment: Have a go yourself first, @MissKnacki . If you get styuck, as a new question, explaining why it didn't work. YOu should, however, simply be able to change the logic above.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `cast()`

```
SELECT *
FROM Production
WHERE cast(Time_Stamp as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
AND cast(Time_STAMP as time(0)) BETWEEN "00:00:00" AND "07:00:00"
```

Comment: Careful with those `CAST`s. `cast(Time_STAMP as time(0))` isn't SARGable, so the indexes won't be used, and `cast(Time_Stamp as date)` *is* SARGable, but doesn't mean you should do it: [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/140734)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Production
WHERE Time_Stamp >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND
      Time_Stamp < DATEADD(HOUR, 1, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())));
```

With this formulation, an index on `TIME_STAMP` can be used for the comparison of both the data and the time.

Comment: This won't work. `HOUR` is not a compatible with the `date` data type as it has no time property; you'll get the error `The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.` The smallest increment you can use with a `date` is `DAY`.

Comment: I can only guess, but probably because it wouldn't know what data type to convert to, `datetime` or `datetime2` (and if the latter, with what scale). As a result you need to be specific.

Comment: @Larnu . . . But it has behaved this way before `datetime2` existed.  The lack of conversion goes way back.  What is ironic is that `0` is converted to a `datetime`.

Comment: `date` didn't exist before `datetime2` existed, Gordon, so *"But it has behaved this way before `datetime2` existed"* is simply untrue. Both `date` and `datetime2` (along with `time` and `datetimeoffset`) were added in SQL Server 2008 ([SQL Server 2008: The New Data Types](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-2008-the-new-data-types/)). You have never been about to use any period less than a `DAY` with `DATEADD` and the `date` datatype.

Comment: In regards to `0`, yes `0` can be implicitly/explicitly converted a `datetime`, however, `0` (or any other numerical data type for that matter) **cannot** be converted to any of the "new" date and time data types. `0` can *only* be converted to `datetime` or `smalldatetime`.