# how to find how many cars are on Rent on a particular date?

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I have a table:

**table 1**

```
carId (INT)
Check Out date (DATE)
Checek In date (DATE)
```

EXPLANATION: This table has a data for a rental car which shows a particular car is checked out on a particular date and checked in on a particular date

I want to find how many cars are on rent on a particular date

**OUTPUT**

```
date (DATE)
NO_Of_Cars
```

Is there a way to solve this problem in python/SQL?

EDIT : I may have posted this question wrongly.
In output, I want date and no of cars for all the dates of a year.
Apologies

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select count(distinct carId) NO_Of_Cars
from table1 
where checkOut <= particular_date 
    and (particular_date < checkIn or checkIn is null)
```

Note that check out and check in are points of custody change. Hence `checkOut <=` means from and including the moment of check out and `< checkIn` means up to but not including the moment of check in. If the check in moment was inclusive `<= checkIn` then the car could, in principle, have 2 custodians for that exact `checkIn` moment (maybe the customer changed cars half way through the rental period).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in SQL

```sql
     SELECT date, NO_Of_Cars FROM table1
     WHERE
         particular_date <=check_out and 
         (particular_date >= check_in OR check_in IS NULL);
```

The date comparison logic is needed over here.

You may refer [Date comparison in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924236/query-comparing-dates-in-sql)

Comment: A car is checked out, then driven around, then checked in. It is not possible for any one particular date to be both before the car was checked out `<=check_out` and after it was checked in `>= check_in`.