# Comparing date in node js using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

> Actually I am using sqlite database(tables).
>   Node.js for back-end.
>   Now I need to get the records that fall under two specific dates.(for example 24.04.2020 11.00 AM to 28.04.2020 02.00 pm)
>   How I do this? in what format I need to store the date and time in database? and how I compare?

Comment: you can use a package like sqlite3 and then use this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924236/query-comparing-dates-in-sql) to create the right query

Comment: Time is also matter for me.. For Example 24.04.2020 11.00 AM to 28.04.2020 02.00 pm

Comment: Then you can use timestamp. Check the [reference](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx) also explore moment.js to manipulate time in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize uses js date. So you can do something like :

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

Foo.findAll({
  where: {

    // myDateColumn < [timestamp] AND myDateColumn > [timestamp]
    {
      myDateColumn: {
        [Op.lt]: new Date(),
        [Op.gt]: new Date(new Date() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
      }
    },


    // myDateColumn in range
    [Op.notBetween]: [new Date(), new Date(new Date() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)]
  }
});
```

I also recommend using moment.js or luxon (personal favorite) to handle the dates.

Using luxon to format dates :

```
const DateTime = require('luxon');

// the reason we love luxon is because it's easy to set the timezone 
const startDate = DateTime.local().setZone('America/New_York').fromISO('2020-04-24T11:00:00').toJSDate();
```

Read more here : https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html

Answer (score 0):

> const currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10); // get current date in ISO format
> try {
> const competitions = await CompetitionTable.findAll();

```
const competitionsWithActiveFlag = competitions.map(competition => {
  const isActive = (
    competition.start_date <= currentDate &&
    competition.end_date >= currentDate
  );

  const competitionData = competition.toJSON();
  console.log(competitionData, isActive);
 
});
```